# Sequentially group entries in a List in Scala

Tags: scala

I would like to group consecutive entries in a list. Here is an example:

```
// Input: 
val list = List("A","B","C","D","E","F")
// Result:
List("ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF", "EF")
```

What is the most idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

Comment: Can you describe "like this"?

Comment: my input is a list of elements and I need to get 3 by 3 element in my new list.

Comment: Why would "EF" belong to the result?

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you would add the signature of the function encapsulating this logic.

Comment: At each iteration, I need to get the previous, the current and the next element, and deal with the first and last iteration

Comment: @nesteban so the expected result should contain "AB" as first element? (prev = <empty>, current="A", next ="B")

Comment: What have tried you so far and what are you seeking to improve?

Comment: @maasg You are right for AB
list.sliding(3) seems to be a good solution to do most of work. But I have to treat special action for first and last iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, since strings are collections in Scala, it's actually even easier than @om suggested:

```
"ABCDEF".sliding(3).toList
// List(ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF)
```

But with the requirement for the `EF` at the end, you might need something slightly different:

```
val letters = "ABCDEF".toSeq :+ ""
val groups = letters.sliding(3).map(_.mkString)
groups.toList
// List(ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF, EF)
```

Comment: It's my favourite response, due to handle the last one. Thanks all to enligth me

Answer (score 0):

Using `take` and `drop` over the sequence of letters you can achieve the same result; let

```
val letters = 'A' to 'F'
NumericRange(A, B, C, D, E, F)
```

and so

```
for (i <- 0 to letters.size - 2) yield letters.drop(i).take(3).mkString
Vector(ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF, EF)
```

Note in the last iteration we take *up to* 3 letters, even that only 2 are available.

This approach is not as efficient as the idiomatic `sliding`, yet it illustrates the versatility of Scala strings equipped with collection methods.